# YouTube IFrame, Angular2, Routing, video starts playing on switch

Tags: youtube-api, angular, youtube-iframe-api

I am using routing with angular2, I have two routes (components) that each have an instance of a PlayerComponent, hosting a youtube Iframe and having a singleton PlayerService behind. If I have a video loaded in one component and I switch to a different route (same video, different component) the first playerComponent is destroyed and the 2nd component is loaded. The video ID is contained in the playerService.  It works, but on the switch from the first playerComponent to the second playerComponent, the video automatically starts to play which I don't want. The embed url contains autoplay=0.

How can I stop this switch starting an autoplay?

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Are there other methods that calls `playVideo`? An alternative I can think of is if you're able to load the 2nd component, you can call `stop` if the play will autoplay. Doing a pre-emptive stop call can be an option you can look in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a completely specific answer, but in my context I have the IFrame in my template with a binding to the embed url.  I found that if I change the embedURL via the binding to my component, it works better than changing the videoId on the YT.Player.